# how to write a 2D array in a table with c language

Tags: c, console

I have a project which is like this:
its a game to between two players in a randomly generated square table from 4 to 10. players roll 3 dices. the first dice and second are used for the location and the 3rd dice is the value which will be put into a table made of '-' and '*'. the table looks like a checkers board. now i want to insert this number created randomly into the table. I don't know how.
in other words, how do you insert an array into a table that was made before?
as you can see the code is below, since this is a shared project with a friend i don't have the table ready but i'll post it as soon as possible. this function is supposed to find the randomize the location and the value. also the size of the array is randomized in another function. it's a mess .

```
#include <stdio.h>
int rolldice(int p)
{
   int x,y,z;
   int ar[p][p];
   x=1+rand%6;
   y=1+rand%6;
   if(z==0){
      z=1+rand%6;
      ar[x][y]=z;
   }
   else {
      printf("other player roll please");
   }
   return z;
}
int table(int n);
int main(){

int size,t;
srand(time (NULL));
size = 4 + ( rand() % 7);
int array[size][size];
table(size);
rolldice(size)
}
int table(int n){
int k,a,m;
int ar[n][n];
for (m=1;m<=n;m++){
printf(" __");
}
for (k=1;k<=n;k++){
    printf("\n");   
    for (a=1;a<=n;a++){
        printf("|__");
        printf("%c",ar[k][a]);
        if(a==n){
            printf("|");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show all the code which is around the problem you have. Define the 2D array. Init it. Output it before. Write a comment "here to be filled randomly". Output it again. This helps us to judge how much you understand the background of your problem.

Comment: Add a function to return a random value in the right ranges (width of the board and length of the board).

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you need. Can you be more specific? We also need some code.
If your table is 2D array, inserting number is straightforward.

Comment: Are you going to react to the comments? If not your question will stay to borad to be answered. If you intend to react delete the question temporarily, [edit] it, then undelete it when it is upvotable.

Comment: Generally this info might help to use StackOverflow as intended. [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: "now I want to insert this number created randomly into the table" Okay. And what's wrong with `ar[x][y]=z;`?

Comment: Your table is `ar[][]` right? All you need to do is to print that 2D array with some formatting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186816/discussion-between-mare70-and-yunnosch).

Comment: @Mare70 the table is generated somewhere else it's like this
|------|------|
|       |       |
|------|------|
in those blank spaces, z must be printed.

Comment: Okay, but im still not sure what you need? If you want value z in that table you can just use `ar[x][y]=z;`? And print whole table later?

Comment: @Mare70 the value z has to be printed in the table every time the player rolls the dices

Comment: So just print whole table after every dice roll?

Comment: @Mare70 the table is printed first. each time a player rolls the dice the value z is add to its place in the table. i think if a print the table every time , i'll lose the previous value of z

Comment: Well, you need to post whole code and much better explanation on what exactly you want to achieve, and whats the problem. We can't help you like this.

Comment: Nothing will be lost with printing, printing should just print current state of the board. So you have starting state of board (empty i guess) and after each roll you add values and print whole table.

Comment: @Mare70 that's what i'm trying to do. how should it print value z in the empty space in the table. I've assigned 0 to all the elements of the array and z is supposed to replace it. the problem is how do i print it in the empty space. what should i do?

Comment: All you need to do is to print 2D array with some formatting, you want me to post code for a function that will properly print your table?

Comment: that would be prefect. thank you @Mare70

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you wanted to see.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

int ar[SIZE][SIZE]=
{
    {1, 0, 3, 8},
    {4, 0, 5, 0},
    {9, 0, 2, 1},
    {1, 0, 6, 2}
};

int main() {
    printTable();

    return 0;
}
printTable(){
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE+1;i++){
        for(j=0; j<SIZE+1;j++){
            if(i==0 || j==0 || j==SIZE || i==SIZE)
                printf(" * ");
            else if(j==SIZE-1)
                printf("%d",ar[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%d - ",ar[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So as you can see this prints 2D array as a table, its also possible to pass that array as a parameter to function `printTable()`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It gives a piece of code for the background of the question. This will either be ignored by OP or used to ask for more parts of the program OP wants. OP seems unable to partifcipate in  clarifying the question. Otherwise you will end up giving OP the whole program without them understanding it. In order to get a decent answer OP should focus on the most basic part they cannot handle. Which might be this array handling, but I doubt it. What OP needs seems to be hand-holding from HelloWorld, via Tutorials to a foundation for this question. Take my hint: Don't.